# select rows from a dataframe, but within a function, so the variables to be selected are unknown

Tags: r, dataframe, select, subset

So, I have to create a function which implements row selection from data frames, but since the variables to be selected won't be known until the actual function call, I don't know what to place in place of the arguments. My code is as follows:

```
observe = function(bayesnet, obsVars, obsVals)
{
  varstokeep = c(obsVars , "probs")

  result = list()

  for (i in 1:(length(bayesnet))) {

    temp = bayesnet[[i]]

    temp <- temp[, names(temp) %in% varstokeep]

    if(length(colnames(temp)) == length(varstokeep)){
      if (identical(sort(colnames(temp)), sort(varstokeep))){
        temp = aggregate(probs ~ . , temp, sum)

        for (i in 1:length(obsVars)){
          #temp = subset(temp, as.formula(obsVars[i]) == obsVals[i])
          #temp = temp[temp$obsVars[i] %in% obsVals[i] , ]
          #temp = temp[temp[obsVars[i]] %in% obsVals[i] , ]**
          print(temp)
        }
        result = c(result, temp)

      }
  }

  return(result)
}
```

What's important here, is that I will have a list of tables (bayesnet), and a list of variables (obsVars) which will have to have specific values (obsVals).

In the inner-most for loop, you can see my different attempts to code for keeping the rows that match the obsVars with their respective obsVals. BUT, since I can't predict what are the values for obsVars, or even the names of the columns of the data-frame, I don't know how to specify that in the code!!!

For example:

```
temp = subset(temp, as.formula(obsVars[i]) == obsVals[i])
```

cannot take a character as an argument, so I have been trying to change the type so that it won't complain.

ANY IDEAS???

Comment: If you are open to a [tag:tidyverse] solution, you should have a read of [this](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Regarding the short example: `subset(temp, eval(parse(text = paste(obsVars[i], "==", obsVals[i])))) ` will work.

Comment: THANK YOU BOTH!!